# Search & Amend User Details

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I'm trying to put together a form and PHP script (below) which allows an administrator to search and update member details via the email address, populating a second email address, forename and surname fields with the retrieved information ready for them to be amended.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect ("hostname","username","password") or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db ("databasename"); 
if ($_POST['search'])
{
    $searchemailaddress = $_POST['searchemailaddress']; 
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from userdetails where emailaddress like '$searchemailaddress'"); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    { 
        $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress']; 
        $forename = $row['forename']; 
        $surname = $row['surname'];
    }
elseif ($_POST[['update'])
{
    $userid = $_POST['userid']; 
    $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress']; 
    $forename = $_POST['forename']; 
    $surname = $_POST['surname']; 
    //replace TestTable with the name of your table 
    $sql = ("UPDATE `userdetails` SET `emailaddress` = '$emailaddress', `forename` = '$forename',`surname` = '$surname' WHERE `userdetails`.`userid` = '$userid' LIMIT 1");
}
}
}
?>
```

I'm receiving the following error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/searchandamend.php on line 13`

with line 13 being this line in my script. `elseif ($_POST[['update'])`

Could someone perhaps take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: The `if` opens a scope which should be closed with `}` before `elseif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$surname = $row['surname'];}
```

should have another `}` afterwards. The one you have only closes the `while` loop. You also may want to consider using some indentation - that really helps seeing errors like this one.

Also, the error basically says it all - the `else if` appears unexpectedly there, so the PHP processor *expects* something else (in this case a closing brace).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this, this resolved the error I was receiving. Unfortunatly though I'm now having an issue with saving the amended changes. I'll have to have a look at this separately. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in a comment to your answer your closing `}` are improperly placed and it appears you have too many of them.

```
if
{
    // stuff here
}
elseif 
{
    // other stuff here
}
```

As was also mentioned in a previous answer if you properly format your code, similar to how it appears in the edited question, you will have a much easier time finding errors like this.

---

I also feel obliged to point you to the [PHP documentation on choosing the correct MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) as the extension you are using is outdated and is not recommended for new project use.